# What is the equivalent HQL query for this SQL query (fetch max value from Inner Join)

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I've worked my way to this SQL query (tested and working as expected):

```
SELECT c.carId, p.color as currentColor
FROM Car c
Inner join Paint p
ON( p.PaintId In (Select max(p2.PaintId) From Paint p2 where p2.carId = c.carId) )
```

**What is the equivalent HQL query** ? (Suppose that Class names and properties are same with the DB Table/columns)

Please note that using 'Order by paintId' and setMaxResults is not a option. I need to fetch the `currentColor` inside the query, as I need to use this in the WHERE statement later

---

Additional info

I have a DB with 2 entities : Car and Paint, where a Car can have one or many Paints.

e.g. this query will fetch the most recent paint for car with carId = 15

```
Select max(p2.PaintId) From Paint p2 where p2.carId = 15
```

I'm trying to create a query where I can filter cars by their most recent paint (max paintId). 
The desired output should be instances of Car Class. one instance per row, so the HQL statement should be like

```
Select distict c 
From Car c
...
```

Comment: What's your desired output, ie should Hibernate return a list of `Car` instances or a simple `Object[]`?

Comment: @mabi, good point, I've edited my Question to answer you. I'll need a list of Car instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an inner join and you do not use p2 in the select clause, you can move the subquery to the where clause.

```
SELECT c.carId, s.color as currentColor
FROM 
  Car c,
  Paint p
WHERE
  p.PaintId In (
    Select max(p2.PaintId) 
    From Paint p2 
    where p2.carId = c.carId)
```

(by the way, `s` doesn't exist in your query.)

---

**Edit**: after reading your additional info:

If the car can only have up to two paints, I wonder why you don't just load it to memory and do it the object oriented way:

```
var car = session.Query...
var carsLastPaint = oneCar.Paints.Last();
```

You can use the special function `maxindex` and access the last value in the Paints list:

```
select c as car, p as lastPaint
from Car c join c.Paints p
where 
  p = c.Paints[maxindex(c.Paints)] 
  and c.id = :carId
```

Look here at the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) for more great functions :-)

Comment: Isn't there a performance penalty checking in the Where statement instead of an Inner Join On/With ?

Comment: I don't think so. The execution plan may even be the same.

Comment: I have already solved my problem, just by moving my check from the `Join` statement to `Where`, as you pointed out. But `maxindex` might also come handy very soon. Thanx a lot !